# PHP Upload Chunk To Google Storage From App Engine

Tags: javascript, php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Hope someone can help me with this annoying problem, I can't get out of it!

I'm uploading an mp4 file in chunk from Google App Engine to Google Storage, I need to be able to do it dynamically with any file I want from a form.

Google app engine does not support uploads above 32M and there is no working guide/example online for do this!

**The problem?**
In the storage, all segments are sent as separate with the same name and therefore only the last segment is shown.

I am uploading a file from JS in chunk in this way:

```
var file=files[i];
var loaded = 0;
var step = 262144*4//1024*1024; size of one chunk
var total = file.size;  // total size of file
var name = file.name;  // total size of file
var start = 0;          // starting position
var reader = new FileReader();
var blob = file.slice(start,step); //a single chunk in starting of step size
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);   // reading that chunk. when it read it, onload will be invoked

reader.onload = function(e){            
var d = {file:reader.result, name:name}
$.ajax({
    url:"chunk_upload",
    type:"POST", 
    data:d                     // d is the chunk got by readAsBinaryString(...)
}).done(function(r){           // if 'd' is uploaded successfully then ->
        //$('.record_reply_g').html(r);   //updating status in html view

        loaded += step;                 //increasing loaded which is being used as start position for next chunk
        //$('.upload_rpogress').html((loaded/total) * 100);
        console.log((loaded/total) * 100);
        
        if(loaded <= total){            // if file is not completely uploaded
            blob = file.slice(loaded,loaded+step);  // getting next chunk
            reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);        //reading it through file reader which will call onload again. So it will happen recursively until file is completely uploaded.
        } else {                       // if file is uploaded completely
            loaded = total;            // just changed loaded which could be used to show status.
        }
    })              
};
```

And i am trying to upload the file in chunk in PHP with Google Storage Resumable upload in this way:

```
try {

  $storage = new StorageClient([
    'keyFilePath' =>  '********************',
    'projectId' => '*******'
  ]);

  $bucket = $storage->bucket('****');

  $fileNameTmp = $_POST['file'];
  $fileName = $_POST['name'];

  $nameFileComplete = $fileName;

  $chunkSize = 262144*4;

  $options = [
      'resumable' => true,
      'name' => 'temp/'.$nameFileComplete,
      'chunkSize' => $chunkSize
  ];

  $uploader = $bucket->getResumableUploader(
      $fileNameTmp,
      $options
  );

  try {
      $object = $uploader->upload();
  } catch (GoogleException $ex) {
      $resumeUri = $uploader->getResumeUri();
      $object = $uploader->resume($resumeUri);
  }

  echo "File uploaded successfully.";

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Seems like your js code sends only one chunk. Could you please show full js code fragment?

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Shared JS works and sends all chunks, I can watch it from the network. I can also see it from the storage, because the last file that arrives and overwrites the others is smaller than the others uploaded.  
You can observe [i] files because more than one file is uploaded at a time, but the shared code takes care of uploading one at a time. Network results -> https://ibb.co/vjtgPgT

Comment: @Delir You can either name your chunks with different names to prevent overwriting or you can use [stream write](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage#streamed_file_write) to upload the file. Please check if it answers your question.